# Iterating over an embedded document in Haml

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, haml

I have an embedded document within a Mongodb document.  The Mongodb document looks like this:

```
[_id] => home
[url] => /
[type] => homepage
[people] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => John Smith
        [rewrite] => john-smith
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => John Q. Public
        [rewrite] => john-q-public
    )
)
```

I'm trying to iterate over the `people` embedded document.  In my app.rb, I'm passing the object to haml like this:

```
DB = Mongo::Connection.new.db("website", :pool_size => 5, :timeout => 5)                                                              
pages = DB.collection('pages')                                                                                                      

get '/' do                                                                                                                          
  home = pages.find_one( :type => "homepage" )                                                                                                                                                                     
  haml :index, :attr_wrapper => '"', :locals => {:items => home}                            
end
```

In my index.haml, I'm can iterate over the entire document like so:

```
-items.each do |item|
  %h2= item
```

But how can I just iterate over the `people` embedded document?  I'd like to do something like this:

```
-items.people.each do |person|
  %h2= person.name, person.rewrite
```

Also, please correct me if I'm using improper terminology; I'm new to Mongo, Haml, Sinatra, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I should learn Ruby syntax a bit more... Here's how I was able iterate into my `people` embedded document:

```
-items["people"].each do |person|
  %h2= person["name"], person["rewrite"]
```